# Fork tree diagram

Tags: c, concurrency, fork

Ok so I am going through past papers and I am stuck on a question about fork() function [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aasp.png) is the diagram I am supposed to recreate using C.

I understand that fork() returns 0 to the child and the childs PID to the parent, but it's really hard to get my head around how exactly this all works.

I have come up with the following but I don't think it works:

```
while(fork() == 0) {
  if (fork() == 0) break;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That loop is *evil* and is known as a "fork bomb". It will very quickly kill your system.

Comment: Also remember that *each* call to `fork` creates a new process, the status of the process creation isn't cached. That means your loop creates *two* processes each iteration: One in the loop condition and one in the `if` statement.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand that it probably isn't wise to run these commands, although the image shows that the children will continue executing fork() until the end of time, I think i need a fork bomb loop. Just not sure how to create it to the specification of the diagram.

Comment: In your example you do only "child2" for the initial parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Debugging your current code:**

`while(fork() == 0) {`

This line creates a child process (we'll call it child process 1). The parent's process does not enter into the while loop. Child process 1 enters the loop.

`if (fork() == 0) break;`

This line is now being executed by child process 1, forking from it to create child process 2. If we are currently executing child process 2 (the 'child' of this fork call), we break. If we are executing child process 1, we will continue the next iteration of the while loop.

Now we have the following process tree:

```
    . p
   /
  . child process 1
 /
. cp2
```

Executing the while loop with child process 1 follows the same pattern as when we passed in parent, resulting in:

```
    . p
   /
  . child process 1
 /    \
. cp2  . cp3
      /
     . cp4
```

**Solution:**

Our end goal is to create 2 child processes, and continue forking from the second child process.

```
while (1) {
    pid_t c1 = fork();
    assert(c1 >= 0); // check fork error
    if (c1 == 0) break; // don't make more children from c1
    pid_t c2 = fork();
    assert(c2 >= 0);
    if (c2 > 0) break; // don't make additional children from parent
}
```

Comment: I think this is perfect and makes much sense thankyou!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create two children processes from each child2 (and initial parent):

```
#define MAX 6

int value;
unsigned u = 0;

do{
    if((value = fork()) == 0) // child1
        break;
    else if(value < 0) // error
        break;

    // parent

    if((value = fork()) > 0) // parent
        break;
    else if(value < 0) // error
        break;

    // child2

    u++;
}while(u < MAX);
```

if you don't want to set a `MAX`, use `while(1)`.

Your program didn't create child1 for the first parent.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, in that you need to create new processes in a loop. *But* the way I think that image mean is that you should let the original parent keep creating processes inside an infinite loop, and the child (all siblings) do their work and exits.

There is also a problem with that image, in that a `fork` call doesn't really create two children, only one child and then the parent continues, which means that "child2` in that image is really all just the "parent".

So to implement something to create that tree I would do something like

```
for (;;)
{
    int ret = fork();
    if (ret == 0)
    {
        // In the child, "child1" in the image
        // Do whatever is supposed to be done
        exit(0);  // Exit the child
    }
    else if (ret == -1)
    {
        // Error, handle it somehow
    }
    else
    {
        // In parent, what is called "child2" in the image
        // Do something useful here...

        // Then wait for the child to exit
        wait(NULL);
    }

    // Let the loop iterate, to create a new "child1"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think the image instructs us to actually create two child processes and continue to fork from the second child process. Sounds like you interpreted it differently?

Comment: I think @AlexPogue is most likely right. Your soloution does make a lot of sense in that if child2 was the parent it would work, however i think your solution would just make many child1 processes from the parent. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Write your code and add boxes for variable values on a sheet of paper and execute it by hand. Each time `fork()` is called:

- make a photocopy of your sheet,
- on the original give some unique non negative value for the return of fork,
- on the copy give 0 to the returned value of fork,
- continue to execute instructions on all sheet of paper in any order you want.

This is a good way to understand what will happen.